# How to set default value of input if value is empty? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example, i have input where default value is 5.
But user remove it using backspace, so after that i want to set default value again.

Comment: If you required that user will not update the value you can use readonly attribute, or you can use blur, change or keyup/keydown event to update the value again to default value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say your input is having a id `test` you can do like below

```js
$('#test').on('change blur',function(){
      if($(this).val().trim().length === 0){
        $(this).val(5);
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text" value = "5" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this is terrible and I don't understand it getting any upvotes.  As soon as you delete the value it puts it back.  Most common users wouldn't understand how to enter a different value.

Comment: But now I can't change 5 to anything else!

Comment: ^^ Like that.  I'd recommend using a change or blur event handler instead.

Comment: Downvoters I updated my answer. If this update is fair enough pleasse consider removing the downvotes

Answer (score 2):

Use `defaultValue` to get the default value if set originally:

```js
$(':text').on('blur', function(e){
   this.value = this.value.trim() || this.defaultValue;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' value='5'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not using `keyup`, as that would prevent the user from deleting the default value and then updating with a new value (since after `keyup` is triggered by the backspace key there will be no value).

Instead I'd suggest using `change` and `blur`, to give (assuming that the relevant element is held in the `selector` variable):

```
$(selector).on('change blur', function() {
    // sets the value of the element based on the current-value;
    // if the value is equal to an empty string ('') once the
    // leading and trailing white-space is removed (using 
    // String.prototype.trim()) then we set the value to the
    // defaultValue (the value held by the <input> on page-load)
    // otherwise we set it to the current-value:
    this.value = this.value.trim() === '' ? this.defaultValue : this.value;
});
```

If you wanted to implement the same functionality in plain JavaScript – again assuming the relevant element is held in the `selector` variable – you could use the following:

```
function defaultIfEmpty(){
    let el = this;
    el.value = el.value.trim() === '' ? el.defaultValue : el.value;
}
selector.addEventListener('change', defaultIfEmpty);
```

Comment: I guess OP and other are not interested in this answer.

Comment: To get this to work on IE 8 (or older) you could use a [`trim()` polyfil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: IE8 why event latest windows does not have it. better upgrade or change the browser for better exp...!

Comment: @Jai: possibly not, but I still feel it's a slightly better answer than the currently higher-voted answer (if perhaps only because of the explanations). I hadn't until now, however, realised that you and I have effectively posted the same answer (I recognise you were first!); but I'll leave mine as well because of the native JS solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `blur` instead of `keyup`, and here's why.

What happens if the user wants to enter in a number (only one digit), but it's not 5, let's say it's (3). If the user backspaces the default number, which is (5) in this case, and wants to enter a single digit, the user will never be able to.

```
$('#test').on('blur',function(){
  if($(this).val().trim().length == 0){
    $(this).val(5);
  }
})
```

Note: You should also use a `keyup` function to check if the value is an integer, `!isNaN`

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution:

HTML

```
<input type='text/numeric/etc' data-default='defaultValue' value='defaultValue' />
```

JavaScript

```
$('input[data-default], textarea[data-default]').on('change blur',function(){
   if($(this).val().length == 0) {
       $(this).val($(this).attr("data-default"));
   }
}
```

Any input or textarea with the `data-default` attribute set will fallback to the default once it's emptied.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="test" type="text" value = "5" />
```

JS

```
//get default value
val = $('.test').val();

$('.test').on('change blur', function() {
  //check if change
  if ($(this).val().trim().length === 0) {
    $(this).val(val);
  }
})
```